# File.ReadLines taking long time to process textfile

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a text file contains following similar lines for example 500k lines.

```
ADD GTRX:TRXID=0, TRXNAME="M_RAK_JeerExch_G_1879_18791_A-0", FREQ=81, TRXNO=0, CELLID=639, IDTYPE=BYID, ISMAINBCCH=YES, ISTMPTRX=NO, GTRXGROUPID=2556;
ADD GTRX:TRXID=1, TRXNAME="M_RAK_JeerExch_G_1879_18791_A-1", FREQ=24, TRXNO=1, CELLID=639, IDTYPE=BYID, ISMAINBCCH=NO, ISTMPTRX=NO, GTRXGROUPID=2556;
ADD GTRX:TRXID=5, TRXNAME="M_RAK_JeerExch_G_1879_18791_A-2", FREQ=28, TRXNO=2, CELLID=639, IDTYPE=BYID, ISMAINBCCH=NO, ISTMPTRX=NO, GTRXGROUPID=2556;
ADD GTRX:TRXID=6, TRXNAME="M_RAK_JeerExch_G_1879_18791_A-3", FREQ=67, TRXNO=3, CELLID=639, IDTYPE=BYID, ISMAINBCCH=NO, ISTMPTRX=NO, GTRXGROUPID=2556;
```

My intention is first to get value for `FREQ` where `ISMAINBCCH=YES` that I did easily, but if `ISMAINBCCH=NO` then concatenate `FREQ` values for that I have done by using `File.ReadLines` but it is taking a long time. Is there any better way to do this? If I take `FREQ` value for ISMAINBCCH=YES then concatenate the values ISMAINBCCH=NO are coming in a range of 10 lines above and below, but I don't know how to implement it. Probably I should get current line where `ISMAINBCCH=YES` for `FREQ`. Following is the code what I have done so far

```
using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(filename))
{
    while ((s = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        if (s.Contains("ADD GTRX:"))
        {
            try
            {
                var gtrx = new Gtrx
                {
                    CellId = int.Parse(PullValue(s, "CELLID")),
                    Freq = int.Parse(PullValue(s, "FREQ")),
                    //TrxNo = int.Parse(PullValue(s, "TRXNO")),
                    IsMainBcch = PullValue(s, "ISMAINBCCH").ToUpper() == "YES",
                    Commabcch = new List<string> { PullValue(s, "ISMAINBCCH") },
                    DEFINED_TCH_FRQ = null,
                    TrxName = PullValue(s, "TRXNAME"),
                };

                var result = String.Join(",",
                    from ss in File.ReadLines(filename)
                    where ss.Contains("ADD GTRX:")
                    where int.Parse(PullValue(ss, "CELLID")) == gtrx.CellId
                    where PullValue(ss, "ISMAINBCCH").ToUpper() != "YES"
                    select int.Parse(PullValue(ss, "FREQ")));
            }
        }
    }
    gtrx.DEFINED_TCH_FRQ = result;
}
```

Comment: It's probably because for every line of text your read... you re-read the entire file in your LINQ sequence.

Comment: @Vlad can you provide a code which implements in LINQ itself

Comment: Why don't just read the entire text file and then process the string var in memory? This will possibly give tremendous performance boost. Best regards,

Comment: @Alex Bell problem is this line is taken based on another line which again linked to another line,in nutshell my outputs each row contains values from several line.So i an using Facade concept here and pushing values to each class

Comment: Regardless of that inner logic, you can first read the entire file and process the in-memory string applying the same logic. It will give substantial performance boost vs. reading/processing file line-by-line. Sample follows. Best regards,

Comment: Format the question.   Really you reading the entire file IN the loop?

Answer (score 1):

`from ss in File.ReadLines(filename)`

This reads the entire file, produces an array, which you are then using in a loop (itself from reading the same file) so that array gets thrown away and then created again. You're reading the same file number_of_lines + 1 times when it hasn't changed in the meantime.

An obvious boost would therefore be to just call `File.ReadLines(filename)` once, store the array and then use that array both for the loop instead of `while ((s = sr.ReadLine()) != null)` and in the loop instead of that repeated call to `ReadLines()`.

But there's a flaw in your logic in even looking at `ReadLines()` repeatedly; you're already scanning through the file so you're going to come across all the lines relevant to the same `CELLID` later anyway:

```
var gtrxDict = new Dictionary<int, Gtrx>();
using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(filename))
{
  while ((s = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
  {
    if (s.Contains("ADD GTRX:"))
    {
      int cellID = int.Parse(PullValue(s, "CELLID"));
      Gtrx gtrx;
      if(gtrxDict.TryGetValue(cellID, out gtrx)) // Found previous one
        gtrx.DEFINED_TCH_FRQ += "," + int.Parse(PullValue(ss, "FREQ"));
      else // First one for this ID, so create a new object
        gtrxDict[cellID] = new Gtrx
        {
          CellId = cellID,
          Freq = int.Parse(PullValue(s, "FREQ")),
          IsMainBcch = PullValue(s, "ISMAINBCCH").ToUpper() == "YES",
          Commabcch = new List<string> { PullValue(s, "ISMAINBCCH") },
          DEFINED_TCH_FRQ = int.Parse(PullValue(ss, "FREQ")).ToString(),
          TrxName = PullValue(s, "TRXNAME"),
        };
    }
  }
}
```

This way we don't need to keep more than one line from the file in memory at all, never mind doing so repeatedly. After this has run `gtrxDict` will contain a `Gtrx` object for each distinct `CELLID` in the file, with `DEFINED_TCH_FRQ` as a comma-separated list of the values from each matching line.

Answer (score 0):

The following code snippet can be used to read the entire text file:

```
using System.IO;
/// Read Text Document specified by full path
private string ReadTextDocument(string TextFilePath)
{
    string _text = String.Empty;
    try
    {

        // open file if exists
        if (File.Exists(TextFilePath))
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(TextFilePath))
            {
                _text = reader.ReadToEnd();
                reader.Close();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            throw new FileNotFoundException();
        }

        return _text;
    }
    catch { throw; }
}
```

Get in-memory string, then apply `Split()` function to create `string[]` and process array elements in the same way as lines in original text file. In case of processing the very large file this method provides the option of reading it by chunks of data, processing them and then disposing upon completion (re: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

As mentioned in comments by @Michael Liu, there is another option of using `File.ReadAllText()` which provides even more compact solution and can be used instead of `reader.ReadToEnd()`. Other useful methods of `File` class are detailed in : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

And, finally, `FileStream` class can be used for both file read/write operations with various levels of granularity (re: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

SUMMARY

*In response to the interesting comments thread, here is a brief summary.*

The biggest bottleneck pertinent to the procedure described in PO question is Disk IO operations. Here are some numbers: average seek time in good quality HDD is about 5 msec plus the actual read time (per line). It well could be that the entire in-memory file data processing take less time than just a single HDD IO read (sometimes significantly; btw, SSD works better but still not a match to DDR3 RAM). The RAM memory size of modern PC is rather significant (typically 4...8 GB RAM is more than enough to handle most of text files). Thus, the core idea of my solution is to minimize the Disk IO read operations and do entire file data processing in-memory. Implementation can be different, apparently.

Hope this may help. Best regards,

Comment: Why reinvent [File.ReadAllText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143368(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: That's right: it can be used to read the entire file. Still, there might be a situation where reading the data by chunks is desirable, so that StreamReader would be handy (I've amended the answer per your comments). Best regards,

Comment: [File.ReadLines()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383357(v=vs.110).aspx) scales better

Comment: Doing this and then using `split` is going to be slower than using `ReadLines()`: It just reimplements `ReadAllText`, and will use a big chunk of memory just to then use another big chunk of memory for the `Split()` before throwing it way.

Comment: The biggest bottleneck in this proc is Disk IO operations. Avr seek time in HDD is about 5 msec plus the actual read time (per line). The entire in-memory file data processing may take less time than just a single HDD IO read (sometimes significantly: SSD works better but still not a match to DDR3). The memory size of modern PC is rather significant ( 4...8 GB RAM is more than enough to handle most of text files). Thus, the core idea of my solution is to minimize the Disk IO read operations. Implementation can be different, apparently. Thanks for this interesting discussion. Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

I think that this more-or-less gets you what you want.

First read in all the data:

```
var data =
(
    from s in File.ReadLines(filename)
    where s != null
    where s.Contains("ADD GTRX:")
    select new Gtrx
    {
        CellId = int.Parse(PullValue(s, "CELLID")),
        Freq = int.Parse(PullValue(s, "FREQ")),
        //TrxNo = int.Parse(PullValue(s, "TRXNO")),
        IsMainBcch = PullValue(s, "ISMAINBCCH").ToUpper() == "YES",
        Commabcch = new List<string> { PullValue(s, "ISMAINBCCH") },
        DEFINED_TCH_FRQ = null,
        TrxName = PullValue(s, "TRXNAME"),
    }
).ToArray();
```

Based on the loaded data create a lookup to return the frequencies based on each cell id:

```
var lookup =
    data
        .Where(d => !d.IsMainBcch)
        .ToLookup(d => d.CellId, d => d.Freq);
```

Now update the `DEFINED_TCH_FRQ` based on the lookup:

```
foreach (var d in data)
{
    d.DEFINED_TCH_FRQ = String.Join(",", lookup[d.CellId]);
}
```